# Changing the default units of measurement units of Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

I want to change the default unit of measurements `mm` and `kg` to `m` and `g`.

How is this possible?

[image: Screenshot of measures and packaging]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i chance this parametters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard-coded in the Shopware core.

To change it, you would need to extend the administration theme (and probably also the store front, if this is displayed there).

For example it needs to be changed here [sw-product-packaging-form.html.twig](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/2c0a9bd2ed74b647abeb706f61838997c68f74b4/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-product/component/sw-product-packaging-form/sw-product-packaging-form.html.twig#L28):

```
<template #suffix>
    <span>mm</span>
</template>
```